# How to add function to specific string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function

I have a string in javascript

```
var Foo = "Bar";
```

I have a function that does a manipulation on this string. to add this function to the string I did this

```
String.prototype.func = function(){
   // code
}
```

But this function will work for every string. I want this function to be called only from my variable `Foo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So apply it only to the string in the variable `Foo`.

You'll need to make it a String object rather than a primitive though.

```
var foo = new String("Bar");
foo.func = function () { ... };
```

Comment: It should probably just be `var foo = "Bar"`

Comment: Ah I see. Carry on then.

Comment: That's why I said "You'll need to make it a String object rather than a primitive though."

Comment: But of course using a string object may introduce other problems.

Comment: With this definition you always have to use `toString()` function

Comment: @Khalid not always - it will be called automatically in some cases. You really have no other choice than something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work only on your variable Foo then simply do the following:

```
var Foo = new String("Bar");
Foo.func = function(){
    //code
};
```

You don't need to add the function to the prototype of String.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to call the function though. Primitives don't have properties. What happens behind the scene is that JS converts the primitive to an object, but discards the object again.

Comment: I tried it before but didn't work. `TypeError: undefined is not a function`